# count is multiplied after adding left join

Tags: mysql, sql

in my query http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16b9c2/3/0

```
SELECT f.name, COUNT(s.letters), AVG(t.numbers)

FROM first f

INNER JOIN second s 
ON s.first_id = f.id AND s.letters IN ('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd')

LEFT JOIN third t
ON t.first_id = f.id

GROUP BY f.id
```

before joining **third table** the count was **4 - 1** but after joining third table it became **16 - 1** which is false because it must be **4 - 1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your average may also be subtly off -- or at least require additional unnecessarily calculation.

The reason is that the number of rows is being multiplied along two dimensions.  The more accurate solution is to aggregate *before* doing the `join`:

```
SELECT f.name, s.num_letters, AVG(t.numbers)
FROM first f INNER JOIN
     (SELECT s.first_id, COUNT(*) as num_letters
      FROM second s 
      WHERE s.letters IN ('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd')  
      GROUP BY s.first_id
     ) s
     ON s.first_id = f.id LEFT JOIN
     third t
     ON t.first_id = f.id
GROUP BY f.id, s.num_letters;
```

For such queries it might be best to move all the aggregation into subqueries:

```
SELECT f.name, s.num_letters, t.avg_numbers
FROM first f INNER JOIN
     (SELECT s.first_id, COUNT(*) as num_letters
      FROM second s 
      WHERE s.letters IN ('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd')  
      GROUP BY s.first_id
     ) s
     ON s.first_id = f.id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t.first_id, AVG(t.numbers) as avg_numbers
      FROM third t
      GROUP BY t.first_id
     ) t
     ON t.first_id = f.id;
```

Comment: would it be worse if i removed the third join and calculated it in subquery like `f.name, COUNT(s.letters), (SELECT AVG(t.numbers) FROM third t WHERE t.first_id = f.id)` with proper index like here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0080aa/2/0 ?

Comment: @JoeDoe . . . That would be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

A bit ugly but gets the answer:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16b9c2/26

```sql
SELECT s2.name, s2.letters, AVG(t.numbers)

FROM (
  select f.id, f.name as name, COUNT(s.letters) as letters
  from first f
  JOIN second s 
    ON s.first_id = f.id AND s.letters IN ('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd')
  GROUP BY f.id) s2
JOIN third t
  ON t.first_id = s2.id
group by s2.name;
```

Whether it's a left join or join or inner join in your case makes no difference since every value is joinable. The "fanout" occurs because the numbers and letters are effectively cross joined since there are no join conditions on them.

The solution suggested does two group by's which gets rid of the crossing by aggregating at every level.

Answer (score 0):

Each row returned is counted, so multiple successful joins from `f` to `s` will then be joined *again* for each successful jointo `t`.

To fix, use `count(distinct ...)`:

```
SELECT f.name, COUNT(distinct s.letters), AVG(t.numbers)
...
```

Comment: got **0 - 1** instead of the actual **4 - 1**