# Count clause -> incorrect count value

Tags: mysql, join, count

We have an issue using a counting combination with inner/left join that we cannot figure out how to solve.
We would appreciate any help on the matter!

We have 4 tables in the example:

```
1: providers: Including 2 providers
2: providers_categories: Including 2 categories. 1 provider can be in multiple categories (this seems to be causing the issue)
3: connections_providers: connecting the providers to the categories
4: reviews_providers: currently we have included 1 rating per provider
```

Goal: to output the review count from the table reviews_providers.

**Issue: Provider 2 is included in 2 categories. The review count is doubled: 1 count for each provider category: A total of 2 reviews are printed even though only 1 entry exists.**

Thank you!

Code:

```
SELECT prov.id, prov.title, prov_cat.title AS category, AVG(reviews.rating) AS rating, COUNT(reviews.rating) AS count 
FROM connections_providers_categories conn 
INNER JOIN providers_categories prov_cat 
 ON prov_cat.id = conn.category_id 
LEFT JOIN reviews_providers reviews 
 ON reviews.provider_id = conn.provider_id 
INNER JOIN providers prov 
 ON prov.id = conn.provider_id 
GROUP BY prov.id 
ORDER BY prov.title ASC

CREATE TABLE `connections_providers_categories` (
  `provider_id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT;

INSERT INTO `connections_providers_categories` (`provider_id`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(2, 2);

CREATE TABLE `providers` (
  `id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT;

INSERT INTO `providers` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'Provider 1'),
(2, 'Provider 2');

CREATE TABLE `providers_categories` (
  `id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT;

INSERT INTO `providers_categories` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'Category 1'),
(2, 'Category 2');

CREATE TABLE `reviews_providers` (
  `id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `provider_id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `rating` enum('1','2','3','4','5') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT;

INSERT INTO `reviews_providers` (`id`, `provider_id`, `rating`) VALUES
(1, 2, '5'),
(2, 1, '3');
```

Our question might resemble the following question, but we do not find the answer / see that it is the same case even thought both questions include multiple counts: [count is multiplied after adding left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048680/count-is-multiplied-after-adding-left-join)
It seems we might need a subquery, but we are not sure how to do this.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: nothing is doubled https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=65c73b104b2a129dc267b5059e5d4d78

Comment: Thank you! However; in the example from dbfiddle, the count was still 2 for provider 2. We need the count to be 1, even if the provider is connected to multiple categories, as it is only one entry per provider in the ratings table. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use subquery top get your result

> ```
> SELECT prov.id, prov.title, GROUP_CONCAT(prov_cat.title) AS category, reviews.rating , reviews.count 
> FROM connections_providers_categories conn 
> INNER JOIN providers_categories prov_cat 
>  ON prov_cat.id = conn.category_id 
> LEFT JOIN (SELECT  provider_id, AVG(rating) AS rating, COUNT(provider_id) AS count FROM reviews_providers GROUP BY provider_id)  reviews 
>  ON reviews.provider_id = conn.provider_id 
> INNER JOIN providers prov 
>  ON prov.id = conn.provider_id 
> GROUP BY prov.id,prov.title
> ORDER BY prov.title ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> id | title      | category              | rating | count
> -: | :--------- | :-------------------- | -----: | ----:
>  1 | Provider 1 | Category 1            |      3 |     1
>  2 | Provider 2 | Category 2,Category 1 |      5 |     1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=21c481ecd0553b5b17ecb5031860a357)*

Comment: Hi, thanks! This works if we only have one entry per provider. If we add ratings, the count will still be 1. We need to count every line, but not double. Thanks again!